# Problem sending MultipartFormDataContent with JSON and Pdf

Tags: c#

I have to send a JSON and a PDF in the same petition, but response from server is "the 'metadata' tag must contain a JSON".

Here is my code:

```
byte[] pdf = File.ReadAllBytes(file);
PetitionJson petitionJson = new PetitionJson();
petitionJson.company_id = "*********";
petitionJson.producer_id = Path.GetFileName(file).Replace(".pdf", "");
string jsonResp = "";

using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
    
    MultipartFormDataContent content = new MultipartFormDataContent();
    
    StringContent jsonPart = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(petitionJson, Formatting.None));
    jsonPart.Headers.ContentType = MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse("application/json");
    content.Add(jsonPart, "metadata");
    
    var byteArrayContent = new ByteArrayContent(pdf);
    byteArrayContent.Headers.ContentType = MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse("application/pdf");
    content.Add(byteArrayContent, "\"files\"", $"\"{Path.GetFileName(file).Replace(".pdf", "")}\"");

    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + token);

    HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync(identityUrl, content);
    client.Dispose();
    content.Dispose();
    jsonResp = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
}
```

The Pdf part si working, but JSON part is not working. Here is Fiddler view:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S8g66.png)

I tried those combinations, and no one is working

```
StringContent jsonPart = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(petitionJson, Formatting.None));//, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
                    //jsonPart.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("form-data");
                    //jsonPart.Headers.Add("Content-Disposition", "form-data; name=\"metadata\"");
                    jsonPart.Headers.ContentType = MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse("application/json");
                    content.Add(jsonPart, "metadata");
```

Edit:
I tried this, but doesn't work

```
byte[] pdf = File.ReadAllBytes(file);
PetitionJson petitionJson = new PetitionJson();
petitionJson.company_id = "*********";
petitionJson.producer_id = Path.GetFileName(file).Replace(".pdf", "");
string jsonResp = "";

var client = new HttpClient();

string boundary = string.Format("------------{0:N}", Guid.NewGuid());
string contentType = "multipart/form-data; boundary=" + boundary;

MultipartFormDataContent content = new MultipartFormDataContent();
content.Add(new StringContent(contentType));

StringContent jsonPart = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(petitionJson), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
jsonPart.Headers.ContentType = MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse("application/json");
content.Add(jsonPart, "metadata");

content.Add(new StringContent("--" + boundary));

var byteArrayContent = new ByteArrayContent(pdf);
byteArrayContent.Headers.ContentType = MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse("application/pdf");
content.Add(byteArrayContent, "\"files\"", $"\"{Path.GetFileName(file).Replace(".pdf", "")}\"");

content.Add(new StringContent("--" + boundary + "--"));


client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + token);

HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync(identityUrl, content);
client.Dispose();
content.Dispose();
jsonResp = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
```

This is the result, with Fiddler:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f8TRF.png)

This is the original result, before changing code:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hiUgC.png)

Comment: A body of a Request/Response can contain text and multi-part attachments (MIME).  Each multi-part starts with a new line with two dashes.  You are just adding json and no MIME.  See following for sample : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/exchange-server-2010/aa563375(v=exchg.140)